# ElastAlert range query is not sending alert emails even though the alert condition is met

Tags: kibana, elastalert

I setup my ElastAlert rule as per below.

```
MyRangeAlert.yaml: |-
---
name: MyRangeAlert
type: frequency
limit_execution: "0/8 * * * *"
index: myindex-*
num_events: 1
timeframe:
  minutes: 15
filter:
- query:
    query_string:
      query: "request.keyword: \"\/api\/rest\/cms\/content\/cited-by\/\" AND response:503"
- range:
  field3:
    from: 150
    to: 200
alert:
- "email"
email:
- "johndoe@gmail.com"
from_addr: "margert@gmail.com"
alert_subject: " High Response Time at {0}."
alert_subject_args:
- "@timestamp"
alert_text: "Average response {0} seconds observed in last 20 minutes."
alert_text_args:
- field3
alert_text_type: alert_text_only
```

Then I inserted data to fulfill the condition.

```
 PUT MyRangeAlert/_doc/501
{
    "request.keyword": "/api/rest/cms/content/cited-by/",
    "response": 503,
    "tags": "account_compromised",
    "alert-triggered": true,
    "field3": 156,
    "city": "Kansas",
    "name": "sameera",
    "description": "desccrption 1032",
    "@timestamp": "2021-01-06T11:31:23+0000"
}
```

However. the alert is not sending an email. I removed the range then it's started to send alerts.
Any suggestion or half answer also highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an indention error worked after adding a space at front to field3.

```
filter:
    - query:
        query_string:
          query: "request.keyword: \"\/api\/rest\/cms\/content\/cited-by\/\" AND response:503"
    - range:
        field3:
          from: 150
          to: 200
```